# Prevent Luxon from adding the timezone offset at datetime object creation

Tags: typescript, datetime, luxon

Creating a datetime object with luxon by providing a day, month, year, hour,minute and Timezone.

I have users supply a date string that is sent via ISO string.

For example

2023-03-02T08:30:00.000Z

I have a copy of the users timezone in my database. I want to add the users timezone to this date without adjusting the offset, the user already entered the time above with respect to the users time one.

So if the users timezone is  Africa/Johannesburg.

When i put this together i want,2023-03-02T08:30:00.00+02:00 but Luxon keeps giving me, 2023-03-02T10:30:00.373+02:00.

Luxon keeps treating my input time as if it is UCT time, then once i add the timezone it adds the offset.

I want to set the timezone without the offset being applied.

Here is the code i have right now.

```
const addTimezoneToDateTimeValue = ({
  timezone,
  dateTimeString,
}: FunctionArgs) => {
  const dateAndTimeHolder = DateTime.fromISO(dateTimeString);
  //2023-03-02T08:30:00.000Z

  const currentTimeInTimezone = DateTime.now().setZone(timezone);


  const finalDateTime = currentTimeInTimezone.set({
    day: dateAndTimeHolder.day,
    month: dateAndTimeHolder.month,
    year: dateAndTimeHolder.year,
    hour: dateAndTimeHolder.hour,
    minute: dateAndTimeHolder.minute,
    second: 0,
  });
  // Giving Me => 2023-03-02T10:30:00.00+02:00 when Timezone is Africa/Johannesburg (+02:00.00)
  // I Want => 2023-03-02T08:30:00.00+02:00

  return new Date(finalDateTime.toUTC().toISO());
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Luxon was using my machines local time when i was entering the initial user input.

To solve this issue just change the first line  from
 `const dateAndTimeHolder = DateTime.fromISO(dateTimeString);`

to

`const dateAndTimeHolder = DateTime.fromISO(dateTimeString, {zone:"uct"});`

Comment: You can also use the `setZone` option, as in `DateTime.fromISO(dateTimeString, { setZone: true})`. Will skip converting the zone to the default zone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not print out a timezone while printing, set `includeOffset` to `false`:

```
DateTime.now().toISO({includeOffset: false})!
```

This prints out a date like this: 2024-01-11T17:20:28.953